# Limit of a series of a side of the Golden Ratio

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, golden-ratio

I try to find a limit of a series of a side from the rectangle of a golden ratio (Golden Cut, Goldener Schnitt). Just for fun to learn more about series. After hours of thinking I could need some help to find a method to determine the limit analytically.

Here is what I have done so far:

Sketch: [image: sketch of the golden cut]

Goal: The goal is to find the limit of the series based on the sequence for side a or b.

Sequence for side a:
$$ a_0 = a $$
$$ a_1 = b_0 = b $$
$$ a_2 = b_1 = \frac{b^2}{a} $$
$$ a_3 = b_2 = \frac{b^4}{a^3} $$
$$ a_n = b_{n-1} = \frac{b^{2n-2}}{a^{2n-3}}$$

Sequence for side b:
$$ b_0 = b $$
$$ b_1 = \frac{b_0}{a_0}b_0 = \frac{b_0^2}{a_0} = \frac{b^2}{a} $$
$$ b_2 = \frac{b_1}{a_1}b_1 = \frac{b_1^2}{a_1} = \frac{b^4}{a^3} $$
$$ b_3 = \frac{b_2}{a_2}b_2 = \frac{b_2^2}{a_2} = \frac{b^6}{a^5} $$
$$ b_n = \frac{(b_{n-1})^2}{a_{n-1}} = \frac{b^{2n}}{a^{2n-1}} $$

Now I try to make each sequence independent from the other. For that I introduce the constant factor c as a ratio of site b and a.
$$ c = \frac{b}{a} $$

under the condition

$$ 0 < c < 1 $$

The sequence for site a is:

$$ a_0 = c^0 a = a $$
$$ a_1 = c^1 a = c a$$
$$ a_2 = c^2 a $$
$$ a_3 = c^4 a $$
$$ a_4 = c^6 a $$
$$ a_n = c^{2n-2} a$$

The sequence for site b is:

$$ b_0 = c^1 a = c a $$
$$ b_1 = c^2 a $$
$$ b_2 = c^4 a $$
$$ b_n = c^{2n} a $$

At this point, I determine the limit of the sequences.
$$ \lim \limits_{n \to \infty} (a_n) = \lim \limits_{n \to \infty} c^{2n-2} = 0 $$
$$ \lim \limits_{n \to \infty} (b_n) = \lim \limits_{n \to \infty} c^{2n} = 0 $$

And then the determination of the limit of the series:
$$ \lim \limits_{n \to \infty} \sum_{i=0}^n a_i = ??? $$
$$ \lim \limits_{n \to \infty} \sum_{i=0}^n b_i = ??? $$

Now I'm at a point where I don't know what to do. The method of the Epsilon-Neighborhood  does not work, because for this I must have at least one guess for a limit. Cauchy criteria as well. I tried to reorder the partial sum of the sequences without success.

I know that it is difficult to find a analytic solution. Maybe it is not possible in this case. But maybe I'm missing a methodological approach that I really need to know about. What would you do at this point?

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Your question is unclear to me. You write $\lim a_n = 0$, $\lim b_n = 0$, and then as to determine the limit of those sequences? Am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: Hey @MartinR ! The notation for a sequence is (a_n) and for a series just a_n. That's how I learned it once. In your comment you removed the brackets from my two lines for the lim of the sequences.

Comment: The usual notation for a [series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Series_%28mathematics%29) is $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n$.

Comment: @MartinR I took my cue from this, where the limit $$s_n$$ was written as the result of a series. https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reihe_(Mathematik)#Konvergenz

Comment: @MartinR Edited my post regarding your notation hint. Thanks!